# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

**Error occuring in the following code**

history.location.pathname is throwing up the error.(line number - 3 and 6)

```
const LinkList = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const isNewPage = history.location.pathname.includes(
    'new'
  );
  const pageIndexParams = history.location.pathname.split(
    '/'
  );
  const page = parseInt(
    pageIndexParams[pageIndexParams.length - 1]
  );
```

I have tried every solution given but still the error is occuring.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="center w85">
      <Header />
      <div className="ph3 pv1 background-gray">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/new/1" />} />
          <Route exact path="/create" element={<CreateLink />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search />} />
          <Route exact path="/home" element={<LinkList />} />
          <Route
          exact
          path="/new/:page"
          element={<LinkList />}
        />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Dependencies:**

```
  "react-router": "^5.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` there is no longer a `useHistory` hook, it was replaced by a `useNavigate` hook that returns a `navigate` function instead of a `history` object.

To get the current location use the `useLocation` hook. You should have already been using the `location` object instead of the `history` object anyways according to the v5 docs as the `history` object is mutable.

```
const LinkList = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const isNewPage = pathname.includes('new');
  const pageIndexParams = pathname.split('/');
  const page = parseInt(
    pageIndexParams[pageIndexParams.length - 1]
  );

  ...
```

You can also likely remove the `react-router` dependency since `react-router-dom` generally re-exports all the `react-router` components, or at a minimum also bump it to v6 so there's no versioning conflict between them.

`Redirect` was replaced by the `Navigate` component in RRDv6, the new syntax for rendering a redirect is as follows:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/new/1" replace />} />
```

Also, in RRDv6 all route paths are now ***always*** exactly matched, the `exact` prop is not part of the `Route` component API.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use, useLocation hook or window.location.pathname to access the the pathname

useLocation returns the current location object.
let location=useLocation()
let path=location.pathname